# BASH: List External drives

Tags: unix, bash-scripting, macos-bigsur

I am trying to make a script that list all disk on my Mac exluding /dev/disk0 and /dev/disk0 (I only want it to show the external and virtual drives) and the name of the primary partition.

Something like this:

```
Disk:
1.- USB1    /dev/disk2
2.- USB2    /dev/disk3
3.- USB3    /dev/disk4
4.- USB4    /dev/disk5
```

I am pretty new to Bash scripting

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#/bin/sh
ls -l /mnt/ | egrep -v "disk0|disk1"
```

Or wherever Mac mounts external drives, if not `/mnt`.

Alternatively, you can use `df` instead of `ls`: in this case two partitions on the same disk will appear separately, so I guess it depends what kind of output you want.